# Is the following index is good?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

What is the proper indexing plan for the below query?

Query 1 :

```
select id 
from room_participants 
where roomId=1 
  and userId=1 
  and status=1 
  and isMuted=0
```

Query 2 :

```
select group_concat(b.phone) 
from room_participants as a 
left join users as b on b.id=a.userId 
where a.roomId = 1 
  and a.status = 1
```

Is it an advisable way to do indexing as per my example below? Does this is what we called redundant index as index combine3 is having the same column as index combine4 and index combine2 is having the same column as index combine1?

```
CREATE TABLE `room_participants` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `roomId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isAdmin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `isMuted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `joinTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `leftTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `kickTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1=join, 2=kicked, 3=left',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`),
  KEY `combine2` (`isAdmin`,`userId`,`joinTime`,`leftTime`,`kickTime`,`status`),
  KEY `combine1` (`kickTime`,`userId`),
  KEY `combine3` (`roomId`,`userId`,`status`,`isMuted`),
  KEY `combine4` (`roomId`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=567 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Please guide me on this. Thanks.

Comment: KEY `combine3` is safe for 1st query, but I'd recommend to add `id` column into it, at the end of its expression. KEY `combine4` is safe for 2nd query, but again I'd recommend to add `userId` to it as the last.

Comment: You can probably replace combine3 and combine4 with an index like (roomId, status, userId, isMuted)

Comment: @Lennart `(roomId, status, userId, isMuted, id)` maybe? it is covering for both queries...

Comment: Yes, that is one option. Personally I find the coverage aspect a bit overrated, but in this case, it is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal for *both* queries:

```
INDEX(roomId, status,   -- first, in either order
      userId,           -- 3rd
      isMuted)
```

Notes:

- In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is tacked onto the end of each secondary index (so it can get to the record).
- All 5 columns (including `id`) are in that index, so it is "covering" for the first query.
- In both queries, the tests in the `WHERE` clause are completely handled by the first few columns.
- In the 2nd query, `userId is available, so the index is covering for that query, too.  (The extra` isMuted` is not harmful.)
- I assume that `id` is the PK of `b`, so that is optimal, too.
- If you add my index, drop `combine4`.  (The left part exactly matches.)
- More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: If I drop the combine4 and using index combine3, the filtered (using EXPLAIN) is only 10%

Comment: and what if the query is only using condition of userId, will the optimizer will be using the combine3 index?   Because I checking the query using EXPLAIN, no index using for the query

Comment: If you only test `userId`, then any index _starting with_ `userId` will be helpful.  See my link.  And/or provide some important queries; I'll suggest a minimal set of indexes that will help all of them.

Comment: How about the filtered (EXPLAIN) not meet 100%?   Would the query be an unoptimized query?

Comment: If Query 2 is using index combine3, it will scan all the rows...

Comment: @anonymous - I find the "filtered" column to be virtually useless.  As for Q2, what fraction of the table is filtered by that WHERE?  Note that I recommended a different order for the columns -- do the `WHERE` columns _first_.